# Twitter api how to check if user follows big account & liked post AND not hit rate limit

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

From what I understand Twitter doesn't give you option to simply check if user A follows user B. You would need to use pagination to retrieve all followers. If the project has let's say 100.000 followers and you need to check this for 10.000 users, it won't be possible because you would hit rate limit.

Considering rate limit what would be the most optimal way to check if:
-user A follows user B where user B has 100.000 followers
-user A liked and shared post XY